# Should I meet my professors at a celebration party?

Tags: advisor, etiquette, academic-life, communication

I finished my exams, the results came in, and I scored well but not in top 10. There is a celebration that all my professors will be at. I am in doubt whether I should go, because I fear my professors, who expected me to finish among the top 10, will be disappointed. Should I still go?

It's like a victory celebration organized by our institution as students have done well in the competitive exam which I also gave but could not go to top 10.

What I feel bad that I didn't come in top 10 which my professors hoped that I would come that makes me feared and creates a dilemma. I wanted them to be very happy because of my result but I don't think they would be that happy meeting me. What should I say to them? Even though some professors won't tell but their facial expression may convey their sadness I think.

Even the students from top 10 would be there so I would feel little shy , what should I do ?
All in all here are my doubts :

- Should I go ?
- How will I talk to my professors ? (I feel bad of not meeting their hopes)
- I feel shy in front of the toppers and I don't have courage to talk to them , How shall I talk to them ? ( once they were my friends but no I feel little sad of being behind )

Comment: Is this a graduation party open for everyone? What's the dilemma? Why shouldn''t you attend?

Comment: I'm also not clear on what the dilemma is.  Why wouldn't you go?

Comment: Yes it's like a celebration party But what I feel bad that I didn't come in top 10 which my professors hoped that I would come that makes me feared and creates a dilemma. I wanted them to be very happy because of my result but I don't think they would be that happy meeting me

Comment: You scored well, so I see no problem. Furthermore, you might want to apply percentage rather than fixed numbers. I.e. being top 50 in a class of 1000 students is still great. :)
It is your own choice if you want to go or not, but I don't see a problem if you did.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear :)

Comment: I am absolutely unclear about this question. What is this celabration party for? A contest? Graduation? Or something else? Please clarify.

Comment: The celebration is Victory celebration in our institution, for many students of our institution have done well and brought 5 out of top 10 ranks in a competitive exam.

Comment: Are you a university student? What is the competitive exam about? Compete against whom? Other institutes? Why is this exam so important?

Comment: It's not a specific party for the top 10, so of course go.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Get over your disappointment and celebrate your achievement. It's important to give yourself a pat on the back when you've done good work, no matter if it's perfect or not. If you only look at what you didn't achieve and not at what you did achieve, your motivation is going to suffer at some point.

As for your profs: If they are not total jerks, they will be very happy to celebrate with you. Nobody in their right mind is going to hold it against you that you didn't meet very high expectations, especially not on an occasion like this. You sound more disappointed than they will most likely be. In the unlikely event that someone is giving you a hard time, just turn around, grab another glass of champagne (or beer) and high-five someone nice.

Comment: "high-five someone nice" - exactly! As well as celebrating the fact that you scored well, you can also enjoy celebrating the fact that others scored well too.